# How to make a <p> clickable javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I currently have this block of code which prints out a list of names associated with a list of people on a team. I am trying to make the text clickable that way you are able to capture the name of the person you clicked and perform an action on a different php file passing the name of the person you clicked. How would I go about doing this

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#your_teams234").change(function() {
               var team = $("#your_teams234").val();
               $.ajax({
                   url: 'functions.php',
                   method: 'post',
                   data: 'members=' + team
               }).done(function(requests) {
                   console.log(requests);
                   requests = JSON.parse(requests);
                   $('#teammates').empty();
                   requests.forEach(function(request) {
                       $('#teammates').append('<p class="myDivs">' + request.fname + ' ' + request.lname + '</p>') 
                   })
               })
           })
       })
       
       
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $('.myDivs').click(function(){ alert($(this).text()); });
   </script>
```

[What the print looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewTLe.jpg)

Comment: Please add much more details and a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: replace '<p>' + request.fname + ' ' + request.lname + '</p>') with  '<p class="myDivs">' + request.fname + ' ' + request.lname + '</p>') and then add this jquery function separately $('.myDivs').click(function(){
  alert($(this).text());
});

Comment: @SmithaKalluz Am I missing something I implemented that and the text is not clickable, here is my implementation I took some stuff out to save space
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('.myDivs').click(function(){ alert($(this).text()); });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
                        $('#teammates').append('<p class="myDivs">' + request.fname + ' ' + request.lname + '</p>')

Comment: You would need to add the `$('.myDivs').click...` in the `ready` function (after the p tags are added) since only then do the `p` tags (of that class) exist.  As you have it they would not exist yet.  May be easier to see what you have so far - add it to post.

Comment: @SmithaKalluz I edited my post to show what I have

Comment: Since the `p` tags are added following an ajax call -  you'll need to add your last statement (the `.click` statement) to inside the `done` callback as the last statement.  They are added dynamically so your static statement does not see them.

Comment: @A__ got it to work One last thing if I wanted to perform a sql query based on the name clicked would that go in the .click method. For example if I want to drop the row with the name that was clicked

Comment: For that I'd follow the ajax pattern already in your code - add an ajax call to a php function which takes a parameter and which performs the drop - add a confirmation prompt as well before dropping - which means the ajax call occurs after confirmation.

Comment: @A__ something like this, where inside function.php there is an if(isset(var1)) 

$(document).ready(function() {
            ####
                        $var1 = $(this).text();
                        alert($var1);
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'functions.php',
                            method: 'post',
                            data: $var1